# $http.get gets deseralized JSON but can't assign it to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I have a problem reading data into another variable, I have this function:

```
var vm = this;

$http.get("/source").success(function(data) {
     alert("Horay !!!");
     vm.myData = data;
}).error(function() {
     alert("Dang It!");
});
```

And then I have the following:

```
vm.view = {
    dataTable:  vm.myData,
    order: {
        classification: 'lastname',
        orderby: '+'
    }
};
```

Using angular under the controller where these are, I can see the value of `vm.myData` and I can pull it too,  but I cannot seem to assign the data to my `vm.view.dataTable`.

Maybe this is not the right way to do it?

I replaced `vm.view.dataTable` with raw JSON items and it does show,
so something is not working between `vm.myData` assignment to data.

Comment: It is not obvious that '**then** I have the following'. $http.get... got no `then`. This means that the expected precedence is wrong. $http.get is async.

Comment: @estus for testing purposes the vm.view is right below my $http call.  I actually have them all under same controller.

Comment: Again, $http.get is asynchronous. You assign `dataTable` to undefined and only then `vm.myData` to `data`. It should be `$http.get("/source").success(function(data) { vm.myData = data; vm.view.dataTable = data })...`. And btw, `success` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @estus 
vm.view.dataTable = data works. how did I miss that ? .. also, what is replacing success if success is deprecated? i guess .then?

Comment: It is `.then(function(response) { ... = response.data })`.

Comment: @estus can you put this as response. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http.get` is asynchronous. `vm.dataTable` is assigned to undefined and only then `vm.myData` is assigned to `data`.

It should be

```
$http.get("/source").success(function(data) {
  vm.myData = data;
  vm.view.dataTable = data
}).error(...);
```

`success` is deprecated. It can be replaced with

```
$http.get("/source").then(function(response) {
  vm.myData = response.data;
  vm.view.dataTable = response.data
}).catch(...);
```

Comment: 10+ for not only answer but for additional info about success's deprecation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to inspect how your data object looks like?
(e.g. by printing it to the console or somewhere else)
Depending on your datasource the array you are expection might be encapsulated in an object and this be found on a deeper "level" of the objects hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, in both cases my data object looks like this: 

[{ "id": "570c9478-5fc8-4c33-82be-19184ada466c", "name": "Willie", "lastname": "Andrews", "email": "wandrews0@myspace.com", "direction": "4382 Hagan Drive" },......] I did print it as I stated the vm.myData does return my json.

Comment: Please remove your answer so you don't get downvote.